# ArrayController sorting - each statement - model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've been trying making a new library app based on the code-school ember tutorial (books instead products... not too complicated).

I'm using the latest ember.js stable release, 1.1.10.

using the *{{#each}}* in my templates,

js:

```
App.BooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.findAll('book');
    }
});
```

html:

```
{{#each}}
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
{{/each}}
```

the following warning is shown in the console

```
DEPRECATION: Using the context switching form of {{each}} is deprecated. Please use the keyword form (`{{#each foo in bar}}`)
```

So I've been trying to use the recommended syntax and I've found this, which is working
html:

```
{{#each book in model}}
    <h1>{{book.title}}</h1>
{{/each}}
```

But when it comes the time to try the *sortProperties* in my *arrayController*, with my *{{#each book in model}}*

js:

```
App.BooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.findAll('book');
    }
});

App.BooksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['title']
});
```

html:

```
{{#each book in model}}
    <h1>{{book.title}}</h1>
{{/each}}
```

my books are not sorted...

I've found another workaround, building a property inside my ArrayController:

js:

```
App.BooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.findAll('book');
    }
});

App.BooksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    books: function(){
        return this;
    }.property(),
    sortProperties: ['title']
});
```

html:

```
{{#each book in books}}
    <h1>{{book.title}}</h1>
{{/each}}
```

It's sorted! 
, but I'm not satisfied...

Is there another cleanest/simplest way to use the *each* statement as defined in ember 1.1.10 and sort my  array ?

Comment: have you tried using arrangedContent in your template ? like:@each book in arrangedContent. Have a look at http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `{{#each book in model}}`
use `{{#each book in arrangedContent}}` or `{{#each book in this}}`

Comment: are `arrangedContent` and `this` are the same thing?

Comment: Not exactly. arrangedContent is the model array that has been sorted. this, on the other hand, is the arrayController itself. By default, each on an arrayController loops through it's arrangedContent but also has each item optionally decorated by an itemController.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'arrangedContent' to get your array sorted in ArrayController.

```
App.BooksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['title'],

    content: function() {
        return this.get('arrangedContent'); // this gives sorted array
    },
});
```

Hope this helps